# Fractional part from a float value in C++ without any inbuilt libraries

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, fractions

```
float f = 735.64;    
int i = (int)f;    
float f2 = f - i;    
cout<<f2<<endl;
```

The value outputted by f2 is simply not 0.64 but something like 0.6400015
I just want to have the value in f2 as either 0.64 or 0.640000.. so could I do it without using any inbuilt functions as such?

Thanks.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: But it could have been 0.6399998 too.

Comment: If you use `double` instead of `float` you'll get closer.

Comment: if you're using a decimal system, build a decimal type

Comment: @MarkRansom: Indeed; but you'll never get all the way there with a binary representation.

Comment: Don't use floating point but Fixed Point.  Search the web for "Fixed point notation".

Answer (score 1):

you have to understand that there is an error in each number used in a computer, if you find the value of that error and subtracted from the solution, then you will get the actual values. I advise you to study all about "relative error" and "absolute error" these concepts are related to numerical mathematics